# Speeding up Android (AOSP) build time

Tags: performance, makefile, android-source

I'm on a Intel i7 laptop with 16Gb of RAM and an SSD. Other than specifying the -j parameter and enabling CCACHE, are there any other tricks I can employ to speed up the compile time of AOSP? Currently it's at ~2hrs.

I have found that -j12 has the best performance given my CPU.

Answer (score 9):

I have two sugguestions:

1.) Set /tmp up as a ramdisk

Here is a great link about setting up your /tmp directory to be a ramdisk in Ubuntu

http://cpiekarski.com/2013/01/02/speeding-up-aosp-builds/

> Sacrificing just a few MB of RAM (~60 MB) for a system temp directory (/tmp) ramdisk can reduce compile time anywhere from ~2%-10% depending on total system throughput (other hardware specs).

To do this all you need to do is add the following to the /etc/fstab file:

```
ramdisk /tmp tmpfs mode=1777,size=2g
```

Where size is equal to the amount of ram you wish to use. In this case 2 Gigabytes

2.) Swap Usage

Once again a link: 
http://ubuntuguide.net/optimize-the-usage-of-swap-to-speed-up-response-for-ubuntu

> There’s a swappiness parameter controls the tendency of the kernel to move processes out of physical memory and onto the swap disk. It ranges from 0 to 100, and when swappiness=0 it tells the kernel to avoid swapping processes out of physical memory for as long as possible, when swappiness=100 it tells the kernel to aggressively swap processes out of physical memory and move them to swap cache.

To check your swap factor, open a terminal and type:

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

Temporarily change swappiness’ value to 10 using following command, and it will be reverted in next restart.

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10
```

To permanently change the value, open /etc/sysctl.conf in a text editor and change the value of vm.swappiness. If this value does not exist add it to the end, for example:

```
vm.swappiness=10
```

As mentioned in other posts, make -j and CCache are also very important and helpful. There's a program called schedtool that schedules CPU processes. They claim that it works well for long-running non-interactive tasks (i.e AOSP builds), but I have yet to try it.

Cheers and Happy Building

Comment: Another good resource that explains ramdisk a little more thoroughly: 
http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-using-ramdisk-for-better-performance-and-fast-response

Comment: Is there any point of diminishing returns for using a ramdisk? If I have 20gb to spare without workflow being affected, should all of that go to tmp or would I benefit from moving some of the source tree into a ramdisk?

Answer (score 0):

AOSP build takes ~2hrs for me also, but just for fisrt time. Next builds take from 10min to 1h, depends which module is modified (`java` side or `cpp` core modules). If you don't modify `cpp` code, than compiler takes cached compiled code, and compiling `java` code takes not so much time.